# Error while reading a big JSON file with Python: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter"

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read a big json file (about 3 Go) with Python. The file is actually contains about 7 million json objects (one per line).

I have tried quite a few different solutions but I keep running into the same error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

The code I am using is here:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('mydata.json') as json_file:
data = json_file.readlines()
# this line below may take at least 8-10 minutes of processing for 4-5 
# million rows. It converts all strings in list to actual json objects.
data = list(map(json.loads, data))

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? It seems to be related to the format of the file but in principle it is in correct json format (I have checked a few lines with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

I have also tried reading a much shorter version of the file (with only about 30 lines) and this operation is successful.

Comment: It's telling you that one of your lines is not valid JSON.

Comment: Whatever is generating your file is creating an invalid JSON. Debug your code to see which line is the offending one (read it line by line and place a break right before the json.loads) or print the line number you are parsing before the json.loads if debugging is not possible. Try to pass that line through a JSON validator. It's most likely not a valid JSON.

Comment: there's a [`jsonlines`](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package that helps with this sort of data.  when it encounters an error it'll throw an exception with attributes `line` and `lineno` that contain info about the offending line

Answer (score 1):

a slightly cleaned up Python 3 version of BoboDarph's code:

```
import json
import logging
import pandas as pd

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def iter_good_json_lines(lines):
    for lineno, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        try:
            yield json.loads(line.strip())
        except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
            logger.warning(f"lineno {lineno}:{err.colno} {err.msg}: {err.doc}")

with open('mydata.json') as fd:
    data = pd.DataFrame(iter_good_json_lines(fd))

data
```

this changes:

- iterating an open file gives you an iterator that yields lines
- use the `logging` module so errors don't end up on stdout
- Pandas >=0.13 allows a generator to be passed to the `DataFrame` constructor
- f-strings!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comment above:
One or more of the lines in the in your data file is most likely not a JSON so Python errors out when it tries to load the string into a JSON object.

Depending on what your needs are, you could either allow your code to fail because you rely on all the lines of that file to be JSONs and if they are not, you want to know (like it does now), or you could avoid parsing non-JSON lines at all and have your code issue a warning whenever one is met.

To implement the second solution, wrap the string to JSON loading into a try block to weed out all the offending lines. If you do this, all the lines that are not JSONS will be ignored and your code will continue to try and parse all the other lines.

Here's how I would implement this:

```
import json
from json import JSONDecodeError
import pandas as pd
data = []
with open('mydata.json') as json_file:
    for line in json_file.readlines():
        js = None
        try:
            js = json.loads(line)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print('Skipping line %s' %(line))
        if js:
            #You don't want None value in your dataframe
            data.append(js)
test = pd.DataFrame(data)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(test)
```